# Searching Data in Database. PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've got table:

```
|-id-|--------name-------|

| 1  |  George Martin    |
```

I pull data like:

```
function search ($query)
{
    $query = trim($query);
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);

    if (!empty($query))
    {
        if (strlen($query) < 3) {
            $text = '<p>Enter 3 or more letters.</p>';
        } else if (strlen($query) > 128) {
            $text = '<p>Too many letters.</p>';
        } else {
            $q = "SELECT *
                  FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$query%'";

            $result = mysql_query($q);...
```

When I type in my search "George", It finds  - "George Martin"

When I type in my search "Martin", It finds  - "George Martin"

When I type in my search "Martin George", It doesn't find me anything.

Is there way to do last pull without making new table with `name` and `second name`?

Comment: You could consider doing an FTS index on the table and search using MATCH instead of LIKE.

Comment: you can split `$query` and match single , single in query?

Comment: As http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php says, "The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions".   You should be using PDO:    http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score -1):

Your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$query%' or `name` ='$query'";
```

Comment: not even a mention about not escaping his variables safely?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets how about adding an answer considering security issues ?

Comment: He won't have to worry about that it he uses PDO (as he should be doing, in place of mysql).